# when Avplayer pause buffering stop after ~60 seconds

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, buffering, avplayeritem

When i call pause() method on an Avplayer istance buffering continue but  after ~60 seconds it stop.
I have tested on iOS 9 and 8.
On iOS 9 i have been setted this:

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
               playerItem.canUseNetworkResourcesForLiveStreamingWhilePaused = true
}
```

On AvplayerItem.
I play an mp4 and also a live http streaming with an m3u8 file but the results it's the same.

Comment: I believe it's the correct behavior: when paused, it will buffer the next minute of content. What is your question exactly?

Comment: only one minute?if i want to buffering more it's possible?if not i have not understand the meaning of this canUseNetworkResourcesForLiveStreamingWhilePaused

Comment: From the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-9.0/): `The canUseNetworkResourcesForLiveStreamingWhilePaused property has been added to AVPlayerItem. The default value is NO for apps linked on or after iOS 9.0 or OS X 10.11, but YES for apps that were linked earlier.` This property controls *if* you can buffer, not *how much*.